# How can a third-party client get and use Active Directory/LDAP permissions?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, saml-2.0, openid-connect

Say in AD there is a group of users called `writers` who can do the permission `write:document`.

In some third-party client such as a Node.js app, is there a way to retrieve that `write:document` permission for a user who logs in?

I have been reading and there are mentions that user on that client would be able to federation authenticate either OIDC or SAML to get back a JWT or SAML token, but I haven't seen an example of whether that token comes back with the scopes like `write:document`.

Example: https://auth0.com/docs/connector/test-dc

I am basically wondering how a third-party client could retrieve and use the permissions already set in AD.

Comment: What do you mean by "permission `write:document`"? Permissions like that don't exist in AD. The group exists in AD. The permission is granted to that group elsewhere. If you want, you can check if the user is a member of that group from Node.js.

Comment: Oh that makes sense then (checking if the user is a member of that group from Node.js). So for "the permission is granted to that group elsewhere", what do you mean by "elsewhere"? I figured that AD stored those groups/roles and their permissions.

Comment: AD just stores users and groups. If a group is given permissions to something, that fact is stored in that "something". For example, permissions to a file are stored on that file. Permissions to a website are stored in that website. And in those cases, AD doesn't know that a group has been given permissions to that file or website.